# Como pré-processar um texto para a aplicação nos algoritmos de classificação do Weka em Java?

Tags: java, algoritmo, weka

Estou fazendo meu TCC onde a ideia, a grosso modo, parte da coleta de tweets e um treinamento de um algoritmo de *machine learning* para classificar esses dados.

Como eu pré-processaria este tweet, sendo que a ideia seria treinar um algoritmo de aprendizagem de máquina com entradas, onde será alimentado com tweets que significam *compra* e tweets que não significam *não compra*, para que posteriormente, a partir deste algoritmo treinado, eu possa dar como entrada um tweet e ele me dê a saída se ele refere-se sim ou não a uma compra.

Já possuo a base de dados dos tweets coletados, e já incorporei a API do Weka em meu projeto.

Comment: Só reescrever a sua base no formato [ARFF](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+(stable+version)). Possivelmente com um pequeno script.

Comment: Entendo, no entanto estou tentando pensar em como ficaria esse arquivo arff, você teria uma ideia de como ficaria o esboço desse arquivo?

Comment: Poste um pedacinho da sua base de tweet (pode ser só 1) que eu respondo pra vc

Comment: "To e morto Galaxy S5 por R$ 2,600" -- "Preciso de um galaxy s5"

Comment: Nesse exemplos acima, possuo 2 tweets, um que demonstra que o usuário não compraria e outro mostrando um tweet de um potencial interesse.

Answer (score 2):

O WEKA lê um arquivo no formato [ARFF](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+%28stable+version%29).

Para criar um arquivo arff, deve-se definir os seguintes cabeçalhos:

### Declaração de Relação

Um nome para a relação, definida na primeira linha do arquivo. Declara-se:

```
@relation <nome da relacao>
```

Se o nome da relação contiver espaços, deve-se usar aspas.

### Declaração de Atributos

Os atributos são declarados através de uma sequencia ordenada de `@attributes`. Cada atributo no conjunto de dados deve possuir sua própria declaração usando `@attribute` que identifica **unicamente** o nome deste atributo e o tipo de dado. A ordem em que são declarados indicam a ordem em que aparecem no conjunto de dados.

Declara-se:

```
@attribute <nome do atributo> <tipo de dado>
```

O nome do atributo deve começar com letra e, se contiver espaços, deve estar entre aspas.

Os tipos de dados suportados pelo WEKA são:

- Números (reais ou inteiros): *Numeric*
- Texto "livre": *String*
- Atributos nominais (texto pré-determinado)
- Data: *Date [<date-format>]*
- Atributos relacionais

#### Atributos numéricos

Serve tanto para inteiros quanto para reais. Se declara:

```
@attribute idade numeric
```

#### Atributos nominais

Valores nominais são definidos quando se provê uma lista de possíveis valores. Por exemplo:

```
@attribute classe {comprador, possivel-comprador, nao-comprador}
```

#### Atributos do tipo String

Usado para textos arbitrários. Declara-se:

```
@attribute tweet string
```

Nota: deve estar entre aspas se contiver espaços.

### Declaração do conjunto de dados

O conjunto de dados é declarado em uma única linha. Declara-se:

```
@data
```

Delimita onde começa, de fato, os dados de instância.

### Dados de instância

Os dados da instância são declarados um por linha e deve-se separar os atributos com vírgula.

---

Respondendo diretamente sua pergunta, uma possível configuração de um arquivo ARFF para o seu problema seria assim:

```
% Tudo depois do % é ignorado. Pode-se utilizar para inserir comentários
@relation compradores

@attribute tweet string
@attribute classe {compraria, nao-compraria}

@data
"To e morto Galaxy S5 por R$ 2,600", nao-compraria
"Preciso de um galaxy s5", compraria
"Configurando meu Galaxy s5", compraria
"Prefiro um iphone do que um galaxy s5", nao-compraria
```

Comment: Entendo, muito obrigado @Beterraba. Vou ver o que faço aqui, desde já agradeço!

Comment: @MaiconFunke Se a resposta resolver seu problema, não esquece de marca-la como aceita ;-)

Comment: Dessa maneira não foi possivel, no entanto eu criei um arquivo arff nesse padrão, mas tive que utiliza o filro stringtowordvector da api do weka, que me gerou o arquivo correto, no entanto não sei como adicionar novas instancias, para o testar o algoritmo. Se você poder me ajudar...

Answer (score 1):

Então cara, eu estou fazendo algo parecido e me deparei com o mesmo problema.
Coletei os Tweets com Python e salvei em um arquivo Json, quando fui ler o json no weka ele nao reconhecia. Eu resolvi da seguinte maneira:

Converti o json em csv e tirei todas as quebras de linha, virgulas, aspas simples e duplas, tirei o acento das palavras e em seguida tentei abrir no weka e deu certo.

Depois de abrir no Weka vc consegue salvar o seu arquivo no formato arff, depois precisei abrir o arquivo para alterar uma linha dele, pois o weka não estava reconhecendo o campo text como string, para isso precisei alterar uma linha do arquivo que ficou assim no inicio do arquivo logo após o `@relation`:

```
@attribute text string
```

Você pode aplicar filtros do Weka no arquivo como por exemplo o `RemoveDuplicates` para remover instancias duplicadas e depois de ter feito o procedimento acima, pode aplicar o filtro de `StringToWordVector` o que vai te ajudar a fazer uma analise de sentimento.